# Convert lists of coordinates to multiple lines based on ID at start of each block of coordinates

Tags: r, command-line

I have a list of XY coordinates along multiple lines. The lines are separated by a single identifier at the start of each block of coordinates. How do I convert this to multiple lines linking the identifier to the lines in R so that I can output them as a shapefile? The problem is in parsing the data to link the ID with the subsequent coordinates.

The data is in the following format:

```
ID1
3285.48 -63.32
3285.14 -64.14
3284.67 -63.56
3285.00 -62.77
ID2
3299.84 -76.82
3299.25 -75.38
3299.96 -75.76
ID3
3299.76 -86.92
3299.77 -86.89
3299.76 -87.04
3299.76 -87.23
3299.74 -87.25
3299.68 -87.22
3299.68 -87.11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read in irregular data if you know the max number of columns by giving column names and a `fill` argument:

```
> data = read.table("./lines.txt",col.names=c("x","y"),fill=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> data
         x      y
1      ID1     NA
2  3285.48 -63.32
3  3285.14 -64.14
4  3284.67 -63.56
5  3285.00 -62.77
6      ID2     NA
7  3299.84 -76.82
8  3299.25 -75.38
9  3299.96 -75.76
10     ID3     NA
```

Then the lines are grouped by how many `NA` are in the second column so far:

```
> data$group = cumsum(is.na(data$y))
> data
         x      y group
1      ID1     NA     1
2  3285.48 -63.32     1
3  3285.14 -64.14     1
4  3284.67 -63.56     1
5  3285.00 -62.77     1
6      ID2     NA     2
7  3299.84 -76.82     2
8  3299.25 -75.38     2
9  3299.96 -75.76     2
10     ID3     NA     3
```

Then you can pull out the IDS:

```
> IDS = data$x[is.na(data$y)]
> IDS
[1] "ID1" "ID2" "ID3"
```

And filter them out:

```
> data = data[!is.na(data$y),]
> data
         x      y group
2  3285.48 -63.32     1
3  3285.14 -64.14     1
4  3284.67 -63.56     1
5  3285.00 -62.77     1
7  3299.84 -76.82     2
8  3299.25 -75.38     2
9  3299.96 -75.76     2
11 3299.76 -86.92     3
```

Then split by group gives you a list of data frames you can apply work to:

```
> par(ask=TRUE)
> lapply(split(data,data$group), function(d){plot(d$x,d$y,type="l")})
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
Hit <Return> to see next plot: 
Hit <Return> to see next plot:
```

Replace that function with whatever you want to do with each line data set, and attach the IDS extracted in the previous step as needed.

Note at this point the columns might still be character so coercion to numeric might be helpful via `as.numeric`.

If you want to make `sf` spatial lines data frame, then proceed:

```
data$x = as.numeric(data$x)
library(sf)
lfc = do.call(st_sfc,
    lapply(split(data, data$group),
      function(d){st_linestring(as.matrix(d[,1:2]))}))
lfd = st_sf(data.frame(ID=IDS, geom=lfc))
plot(lfd,lwd=5)
```

to get...

[image]

Comment: that fill part is sweet, really neat

Comment: This is a great answer to the problem @Spacedman - do you think it would scale well with very large datasets (millions of lines)? I have tried to do something similar with the unix utility awk but like you I had to go through the data multiple times processing and writing to get a fairly simple additional column?

Comment: Took about ten seconds to process a 1,000,000 line file that had 10,000 features each with 100 points in it, resulting in a spatial sf data frame with 10,000 features.

Comment: Well that seems sufficiently fast! Thanks again @Spacedman